# windows server 2012 Hyper-v automatic action

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, hyper-v

I have a windows server 2012 with hyper-v on it,

My question here is how to stop a VM in hyper-v after like 30 days automatically, with out me touch anything, the point here that i have many clients and VMs, so i want the system do the overdue invoice stop service for me, is that possible ?

Thanks.

Comment: How will Hyper-V know that your customer invoice is overdue and that the VM should be shut down? Or do you just want Hyper-V to randomly shut down your VM's automatically? Your question doesn't make a lot of sense from a technical or operational standpoint.

Comment: Hello, It's not like that i mean is there any way to stop any vm in my hyper-v after a month like i want the mv to stop after 30 days how my i schedule this , not the system me i will pick a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a PowerShell script to run on the host, it can check a database for overdue invoices and if found stop the VM for that customer, like:

```
Stop-VM -Name foobar -Save
```

Schedule the script to run every day or once a week.

Comment: Hello, "Stop-VM -Name foobar -Save"  this command is working but how to make it run from it self let's say tomorrow or after week or month? is there any crontab like Linux ??

Comment: The Windows version of crontab is `Task Scheduler` you can use the GUI or PowerShell commands to set up a scheduled task to run your command whenever you like. Search online for help on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a scheduled task on the VM itself, using the "shutdown" command and set the task to run in 30 days. There is no built in functionality in Hyper-V to schedule VM shutdowns/restarts.

Comment: Hello, you mean "shutdown" command for the host server or the vm and how i do it fot the vm ?

Comment: Shutting your host server down will obviously stop all guests. I mentioned a task to run on the guest itself. If you are unfamiliar with setting up Windows scheduled tasks, you have some reading to do.